# OpenTBS enter formulas into xlsx cells

Tags: opentbs

I am trying to set up an Excel file from php using OpenTBS and it would be convenient if I could save formulas into some of the cells. E.g. when I have =A1 in B1, I'd like to see the contents of A1 in B1.

When I use MergeBlock(), and specify a string that starts with an equal sign, the formula just appears as a string in the generated Excel file. Is there a trick to turn this into an Excel formula?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of formulas in an XLSX template is explained in the XLSX [demo example](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo) provided with the OpenTBS furniture.

It says :

> You may consider the following before building your own Microsoft
> Excel template:
>
> - Do not use a formula in a cell that may have its position changed after the merge (for example under a TBS block). Otherwise Excel will
>   raise an error message.
>   This is because the location of formulas are saved a second time in another sub-file for the order of evaluation.
> - If a formula uses a reference to a cell that has moved during the merge, then the reference will not be arraged to be the new cell
>   reference.
> - You cannot change picture using "ope=changepic". This is because drawing information are not saved directly in the sheet.

See the demo example for an example of formula not moved after a merge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case the formula is not below a TBS block, it is within a TBS block. My Excel sheet has a header and a large TBS block. The TBS block has some formulas. These formulas are written by the same one MergeBlock() call. The formulas point to cells to above the rows, or to other cells within the same row that is being written.